# Getting low memory warning but I don't appear to be leaking memory

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

My application is closing without any error messages and re-launching automatically after switching activities approximately 20 or 30 times.  I'm testing this by tapping a button that relaunches the current activity with different data (and cycles back around to the beginning once the end of the data is reached).  The activity is launched with the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag so there should only ever be one instance of the activity in memory at a time.  If I set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` the problem still occurs.

This appears in the logcat output when the app crashes:

```
06-28 19:32:10.472: I/ActivityManager(115): Process com.mypackage.myapp (pid 3718) has died.
06-28 19:32:10.476: I/WindowManager(115): WIN DEATH: Window{406d06e0 com.mypackage.myapp/com.mypackage.myapp.welcome.LoginActivity paused=false}
06-28 19:32:10.480: E/InputDispatcher(115): channel '406ade20 com.mypackage.myapp/com.mypackage.myapp.matchup.MatchUpActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
06-28 19:32:10.480: E/InputDispatcher(115): channel '406ade20 com.mypackage.myapp/com.mypackage.myapp.matchup.MatchUpActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-28 19:32:10.535: I/WindowManager(115): WIN DEATH: Window{406ade20 com.mypackage.myapp/com.mypackage.myapp.matchup.MatchUpActivity paused=false}
06-28 19:32:10.539: I/WindowManager(115): WIN DEATH: Window{407a8230 com.mypackage.myapp/com.mypackage.myapp.fightcard.FightCardActivity paused=false}
06-28 19:32:10.566: I/ActivityManager(115): Start proc com.mypackage.myapp for activity com.mypackage.myapp/.fightcard.FightCardActivity: pid=3915 uid=10053 gids={3003}
06-28 19:32:10.574: I/ActivityManager(115): Low Memory: No more background processes.
```

Normally this would tell me that the app is leaking memory, however if I perform this test while watching the DDMS perspective in Eclipse, I can see that the allocated memory is stable, and in fact the app will often crash even when the % used is sitting around 50% (which is where it sits most of the time).  The heap size and allocated memory are not increasing.

I have extensively used `MAT` on the app and while I did find memory leaks previously, I have solved them and can no longer find any other problems with that tool.

I've been able to recreate this problem on a Nexus S running Gingerbread, but it doesn't appear to be reproducible on a Galaxy Nexus running 4.0.4 (however that might be due to the fact that the heap is larger on the Galaxy).

What am I missing?

Comment: Does your app happen to create Bitmaps without recycling them? This is one memory hog that can accumulate across activity changes.

Comment: did you find GC call frequently in Logcat ?

Comment: I do have bitmaps that are actually pretty large.  I'm explicitly recycling these when the activity is paused.  GC runs on every activity change.

Comment: Actually, I'm recycling them in onDestroy().  Could it be that the next activity is launching before the old bitmaps are recycled, which is putting the memory usage over the limit?

Comment: Yes, out of experience it is likely that onDestroy is executed after the next activity already started. onPause is a good spot for recycling unused bitmaps.

Comment: sounds like you are leaking an Activity context to me... are you playing with `static` drawables/bitmaps/etc. in weird ways?

Comment: No static images.  If that was the case, wouldn't I see the allocated memory increasing unbounded in DDMS?

Comment: If I move the `recycle()` call to `onPause()`, I get a `trying to use a recycled bitmap` error even though I'm not calling anything on the bitmaps after `onPause()`

Comment: OK - I'm successfully recycling the images in `onPause()` but the original problem is still occurring exactly as before.

Comment: Have you tried watching the memory usage while running using `adb shell dumpsys meminfo <your apps package name>` ? This may give you a better idea of what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David Wasser's suggestion above led me to the solution.  I noticed when I ran the command mentioned, I was getting a whole bunch of custom font asset allocations:

```
zip:/data/app/com.mypackage.myapp-2.apk:/assets/DINNextLTPro-MediumCond.otf: 98K
```

These allocations appeared to be increasing very quickly as I changed activities.  Some googling led me to this link: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904

So it appears that there is an Android bug related to using custom fonts.  The following workaround was taken from the link above:

```
public class Typefaces {
    private static final String TAG = "Typefaces";

    private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(Context c, String assetPath) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
                try {
                    Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
                            assetPath);
                    cache.put(assetPath, t);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface '" + assetPath
                            + "' because " + e.getMessage());
                    return null;
                }
            }
            return cache.get(assetPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially we're caching the instances of the custom font asset so each one only needs to be instantiated a single time.